# sending email using java mail-api fails

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Desperatly trying to send an email to myself:

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.web.de");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myveryownemail@web.de"));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress[]{new InternetAddress("myveryownemail@web.de")});
        msg.setSubject("whatever");
        msg.setContent("whatever", "text/plain");

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.web.de", 587, "myveryownemail", "myveryownandcorrectpassword");

        Transport.send(msg);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I´m getting
**javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified?**
but username and password is absolutly correct (tried username with and without the @web.de). password is the one I use for normal login into my mail account.

don´t get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In past I solved similar issue adding this:

```
if ("true".equals(emailConfig.get("mail.smtp.auth"))) {
    session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(emailConfig.get("mail.smtp.user"), emailConfig.get("mail.smtp.password"));
        }
    });
}

Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailFromAddress));
msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailToAdrress));
msg.setSubject(mailSubject);
msg.setText(mailMessageBody);
Transport.send(msg);
```

Session is **javax.mail.Session**

Answer (score 3):

> Create the **javax.mail.Session** object like below, with your username and
>   password:-

```
 Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });
```

Ref tutorial:- http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Answer (score 1):

Set the below properties with your smtp user and password

```
props.put("mail.smtp.user", "myuser");
props.put("mail.smtp.password", "mypwd");
```

Reference : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Comment: i already tried. i tried a lot. a lot according to tutorials. nothing works

Comment: Then try as Amit mentioned.  `Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });`

Comment: There is [no such property as `mail.password`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/).

Comment: There is no mail.smtp.password property either.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have included the "mail.jar" and "activation.jar" in your project. This [link](http://javainfinite.com/java/send-email-using-gmail-in-java/) may help you

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the Transport.send static method, which ignores the Transport instance you created and connected.  Call the sendMessage method instead, or skip creating your own Transport instance and call the static send method that takes a username and password.

This is one of the [JavaMail common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).